# Language member explanation

Tags: formal-languages, terminology, regular-expressions

Given the following formal language $L$:

$$    L=\{ww \mid w\in\{a,b\}^*\}$$

Why is $a$ not a member of this language?

So what is $\{a,b\}^*$ exactly? I thought it means $(a+b)^*$?

Comment: Note: the language $L$ as given is not regular. Not even context-free.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The notation $\{a,b\}^*$ stands for all strings over the alphabet $\{a,b\}$. A word is in the language $L$ if it is of the form $ww$, where $w$ is an arbitrary word over the alphabet $\{a,b\}$. For example, taking $w = aba$, we see that $abaaba \in L$. If $w$ has length $n$ then $ww$ has length $2n$, and in particular every word in $L$ has even length. So $a \notin L$. But this idea isn't enough to prove that $ab \notin L$.

If $x$ is a word of odd language, then $x \notin L$. If $x$ has length $2n$, then write $x=yz$, where $y$ consists of the first $n$ characters, and $z$ consists of the last $n$ characters. Then $x \in L$ if and only if $y=z$. If $x=ab$ then $y=a$ and $z=b$ and so $y \neq z$, implying $ab \notin L$.

Answer (score 1):

The language states that each word of the language consists of two parts `w`, which a condition on the `w`.

As a result you always need a even number of characters in each word of this language. In consequence `a` is not a member of L!

The words `w` created by `{a,b}*` are like you stated: A arbitrary sequence of `a` or `b` characters (a sequence of zero characters as well).
For a member-word of the language, however, these words are "doubled" or concatenated to each other.